# How to boot and install the Ubuntu server image on QEMU -nographic without the GUI?

Tags: qemu

At [How to run Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on QEMU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792) I have described in detail how to boot and install the desktop  Ubuntu image on QEMU.

Now I wanted to do a similar setup for the server image to  try keep things more minimal:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso
```

I have installed the server image with the GUI previously, and the setup seems to be text based, so I thought it might work.

But then, if I just add [the usual](https://serverfault.com/questions/471719/how-to-start-qemu-directly-in-the-console-not-in-curses-or-sdl):

```
-nographic -serial mon:stdio
```

as in:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso \
  -drive file=ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.img.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
  -enable-kvm   -m 2G   -smp 2   -vga virtio -nographic -serial mon:stdio
```

I just never get anything on the terminal serial.

I also tried to mount the image to see what was inside:

```
mkdir mydir
sudo mount ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso mydir
```

to see what was inside, and:

```
cat mydir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

indicates that there is no `console=ttyS0` option on the command line, which might explain why the terminal is empty.

I can't edit the ISO file however without first going into a GUI session, as it is mounted readonly.

I have already used the Cloud image previously, and it is great: [Is there any prebuilt QEMU Ubuntu image(32bit) online?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171) but I can't use it this time because I need GRUB for something (edit: nevermind, the cloud image does have GRUB, just it is hidden by default, see: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time using serial console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924913/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time-using-serial-console/1110209#1110209) )

Related: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time using serial console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924913/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time-using-serial-console) I managed to get GRUB to show on the terminal after changing the GRUB configuration with the GUI as shown in that thread.

Tested on an Ubuntu 16.04 host.

Comment: I have this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

There is this option you can give qemu:

```
-display curses

   Display video output via curses. For graphics device models which support a text mode, QEMU can display this output using a curses/ncurses interface.Nothing is displayed when the graphics device is in graphical mode or if the graphics device does not support a text mode. Generally only the VGA device models support text mode.
```

source: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/invocation.html?highlight=curses

But im asuming this wont fix the problem or is a solution for your or others problem.